# htaccess to convert page/account.php?uname=user_name to page/user_name

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a website running on my localhost. The account of any user is associated as **website.com/account.php?uname=User_name**, i.e, I pass user name as a parameter. What I want is the parameter should be passed as **website.com/User_name** or **website.com/account/User_name**. I've seen a lot of htaccess tutorials but none helped me. I tried creating an index.php inside account folder, but I don't think it is a good practice, and also a parameter will have to be passed there also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below code in your **.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /account.php?uname=$1 [L]
```

> Original URL

```
http://website.com/account.php?uname=User_name
```

> rewritten URL

```
http://website.com/User_name
```

If you want Rewritten URL with prefix **account** like below

```
http://website.com/account/User_name
```

> then add below code in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^account/([^/]*)$ /account.php?uname=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Sorry but the above method is not working. I tried, it says object not found even though I created an account.php file

Comment: there is no need of account.php file directly put on htaccess

Comment: But I have an index.php file. So how will the variables pass